# Is NeoPixel used in Amazon Echo series?

Tags: optics

- Is it true that NeoPixels are used in Amazon Echo series?
- If so how many NeoPixel LED's are used?
- If so what are the optics used to give a smooth streak of colours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, NeoPixel LEDs are not used, they use custom LEDs, then a circular strip of opaque plastic is used to diffuse the light from the individual LEDs. There are twelve LEDs on the Echo.

Comment: By custom do you mean a some other brand than NeoPixel, or the in-house made LED's by Amazon?

Comment: @iamnagaky They have SMD LEDs directly attached to one of the three circuit boards.

Comment: @iamnagaky I think s/he just means plain RGB LEDs with no fancy control stuff.